# Как отобразить результаты скрипта в HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Доброго времени суток!

Есть такой код на JS:

```
 let file = document.getElementById('input');
file.onchange = function(e) {
  let ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
  switch (ext) {
    case 'json':
      break;
    default:
      alert('Выберите файл .JSON');
      this.value = '';
  }
};


    let filejson = document.getElementById('input');
     
    filejson.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    let file =  filejson.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
    const textJSON = event.target.result;
    var array = textJSON.split('\n');
    document.write(array);

    let spaces = 4;
 

      let jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
      let jsonObj; 
      try{
        jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
      }
     
      function parseJSON(obj, nesting = 0){
        if(obj instanceof Object){
          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            console.log("-".repeat(nesting * spaces), key);
            parseJSON(value, nesting + 1);
          }
        }
        else{
          console.log("-".repeat(nesting * spaces), obj);
          return;
        }
      }
       parseJSON(jsonObj);

        }
    const testJSON = reader.readAsText(file);

        });
```

Вот его результат в консоли: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно реализовать такой функционал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на элемент будет показываться его значение (в отдельном div) Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, тебе нужно записывать полученные данные из скрипта в HTML страничку.

Для этого найди нужный тебе HTML элемент, а после запиши в него значение:

```js
const email = 'useremail@domain.com';
const emailElem = document.getElementById('email');
emailElem.innerHTML = email;
```

```html
<div id="email"></div>
```